# Wrap Table and sent e-mail with a Button

Tags: javascript, html-table, html-email

Is possible with one JavaScript function and a button send email an already printed html table ?

```
<table id="mytable">
</table>
```

Comment: You have to connect to SMTP server which you can't (usually) do in JS (and user can see your login and password). Try using some server-side scripts to do this. See http://php.net/mail

Comment: Yes server side with PHP but how wrap the table into a $msg variable easy ? This i think is the right question...

Comment: `document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML` gives you HTML inside the `<table>` and `document.getElementById("mytable").outerHTML` gives HTML including the `<table>` tags. Then send it to the server (XHR, form, ...). Remember thet user can quite easily modify it to send HTML what you don't want, so re-encoding to other frmat will be better.

Comment: Thanks jiwopene it work and i send it with a form... Is not very good practice becouse css styles, but i have so many diferents table and i can't for now re-encoding all my site...

Comment: You can include style in your e-mail using `<style>` tag. Example: `<style>/*Your CSS*/</style>`. In message, use only minimal styles, not complete stylesheet from your webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a PHP function and i call everyware i need to send my results.

The call

```
<?php SendEmailForm("MyIdElementToSend"); ?>
```

and the function

```
function SendEmailForm ($MyIdElementToSend){
?>
<form id="EMailForm" action="SendMail.php?SendMail=true" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hide">
                <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("msg").value = document.getElementById("<?php echo $MyIdElementToSend ?>").outerHTML;
</script>
```